# When Running SSIS Data Flow Task with XML Source and Inline Schema Nothing is Read

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a large XML file that I have been trying to load into a SQL table using a Data Flow task in SSIS.  I have an XML Source, and an ADO.NET Destination.  When I run the package, even though the XML file has many records, nothing is read like it cannot read the child elements.  The XML file has inline XSD so I have checked that in the properties.  For the life of me I cannot get it to read the records.  Please find the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="StationID" type="xs:int" />
                <xs:element name="Station" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="60" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Market" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="30" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Format" minOccurs="0">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:maxLength value="30" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="earliest_report_data" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="FCC_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
        <xs:selector xpath=".//Table" />
        <xs:field xpath="StationID" />
      </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <StationID>2978</StationID>
        <Station>WKDD-FM</Station>
        <Market>Akron</Market>
        <Format>Hot AC</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-11-28T00:00:00-05:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>43863</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
        <StationID>2975</StationID>
        <Station>WNIR-FM</Station>
        <Market>Akron</Market>
        <Format>News/Talk</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-11-28T00:00:00-05:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>41077</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
        <StationID>2977</StationID>
        <Station>WONE-FM</Station>
        <Market>Akron</Market>
        <Format>Classic Rock</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-11-28T00:00:00-05:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>43873</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table4" msdata:rowOrder="3">
        <StationID>2976</StationID>
        <Station>WQMX-FM</Station>
        <Market>Akron</Market>
        <Format>Country</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-11-28T00:00:00-05:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>43872</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
        <StationID>2804</StationID>
        <Station>WAJZ-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Rhythmic</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>35537</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table6" msdata:rowOrder="5">
        <StationID>2797</StationID>
        <Station>WFLY-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Top 40</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>832</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table7" msdata:rowOrder="6">
        <StationID>2793</StationID>
        <Station>WGDJ-AM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>News/Talk</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2009-06-28T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>40768</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table8" msdata:rowOrder="7">
        <StationID>2795</StationID>
        <Station>WGNA-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Country</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>72118</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table9" msdata:rowOrder="8">
        <StationID>2791</StationID>
        <Station>WGY-AM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>News/Talk</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>15329</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table10" msdata:rowOrder="9">
        <StationID>2805</StationID>
        <Station>WINU-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Alternative Rock</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2008-12-06T00:00:00-05:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>27551</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="10">
        <StationID>2803</StationID>
        <Station>WKKF-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Top 40</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>17030</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="11">
        <StationID>2798</StationID>
        <Station>WKLI-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Country</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>4682</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table13" msdata:rowOrder="12">
        <StationID>2807</StationID>
        <Station>WPBZ-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>AC</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>40767</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table14" msdata:rowOrder="13">
        <StationID>2799</StationID>
        <Station>WPYX-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Classic Rock</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>73911</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table15" msdata:rowOrder="14">
        <StationID>2806</StationID>
        <Station>WQBK-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Classic Rock</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>6613</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table16" msdata:rowOrder="15">
        <StationID>2792</StationID>
        <Station>WROW-AM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Adult Standards</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>54853</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table17" msdata:rowOrder="16">
        <StationID>2800</StationID>
        <Station>WRVE-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Hot AC</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>15330</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table18" msdata:rowOrder="17">
        <StationID>2815</StationID>
        <Station>WTMM-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Sports</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2010-04-29T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>22004</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table19" msdata:rowOrder="18">
        <StationID>2802</StationID>
        <Station>WTRY-FM</Station>
        <Market>Albany, NY</Market>
        <Format>Classic Hits</Format>
        <earliest_report_data>2006-08-18T00:00:00-04:00</earliest_report_data>
        <FCC_ID>8563</FCC_ID>
      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple namespaces.  Use an XML task.  Operation type XSLT.  Create the connection for your original XML file and your "transformed" XML file will be a new XML file connection for the Output.

For Second Operand, choose Direct Input.

Use the following in the Second Operand.  You will then be able to point your XML source at the Output file and generate the XSD to load correctly to SQL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" />
   <xsl:template match="/|comment()|processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the inline Schema. Just ask SSIS to generate it for you. SSIS generated Schema guaranties that SSIS understands it.

Comment: This comes from a webservice so the inline schema is included.  I'm thinking about just using an XSLT transformation to be able to load.

Comment: It is because there are multiple namespaces I believe.

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured it out and everything is working for you.